# Android Facebook posting

Tags: android, facebook, textview

Hello I was wondering is it possible to post the android  textview to facebook as a status or would it be only possible with the edittext feature if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both TextView and EditText have a method getText() that you can use to retrieve the text, you can then post this to Facebook using the API - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android